# how to give an alert whenever the back-end data gets changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, ecmascript-5

We have simple json like this

```
{
    name: "Johnson"
}
```

Am using ajax to show up the name as below

```
$.ajax({
    url: /info.json,
    success: function(data) {
        $('<span><b>' + data.name + '</b></span>').append('body')
    }
});
```

Output Html is like below

```
<body>
    <label> name </label>
    <span><b>Johnson</b></span>
</body>
```

Let us assume that the name what we are getting now gets changed from "Johnson" to "Michael".

Output Html after the name gets changed as below:

```
<body>
    <label> name </label>
    <span><b>Michael</b></span>
</body>
```

Whenever the name gets changed we want show up the popup.There are no events bind to the HTML document, How to achieve this?

In developer tools , using break-on option I can able to debug it. Is there any other way in Javascript to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Just use `setInterval` to run your Ajax every 10 seconds or so (depends on your use case, but don't do it more often than about every 5 seconds). The only alternative is to use web sockets to send data from server to client when a change is made - this is the only option if you need genuinely "real time" data, but it requires you to be able to change the server side code (it's not clear if you can from your question), and is also more difficult to do.

Comment: Using setInterval leads to the memory leak. Does my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should try setInterval() of javascript, it checks your file again and again in several time that you have to define like

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: /info.json,
        success: function (data) {
           $('<span><b>'+data.name+'</b></span>').append('body')
        }
   });
},3000) //it will call after each 3 sec
```

it may helps you :)

Comment: Not a good idea at all. DDoS will occur in this case. Think 10K users using this code then or even more.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX gets no notification, when data changes on the server.

You could try **long polling** or a similar technique, or (if your server and application support it) do it with **websocket** or HTTP/2.

The latter may require some development (even server upgrade) depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Shall we use mutation Observer for the above case, so that whenever data gets changed, user will get a notification via pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

I have created list items, whenever we add the items we will get the popup. No event is binded to the DOM.I have achieved this by using Mutation observer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ol contenteditable oninput="">
  <li>Enter the items</li>
</ol>
<script>
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
  var list = document.querySelector('ol');

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        var list_values = [].slice.call(list.children)
            .map( function(node) { return node.innerHTML; })
            .filter( function(s) {
              if (s === '<br>') {
                return false;
              }
              else {
                return true;
              }
         });
        alert(list_values);
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(list, {
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a function for content modification event. You can try with this code :

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'span b', function(){
    console.log("name modified");
    // add your action
})
```